# Concatinated list column value validation with another list in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2013

I have **3 columns(A,B,C)** in my Excel sheet with first two columns(**A** & **B**) having the selection list as `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}` and the third column(**C**) will get auto populated with the value based on the selections made in **A** & **B** as `A1-B1`

Eg:

||   **A**   |   **B**  |    **C**     ||

||   a   |    f   |   a-f    ||

||   d   |   g   |   d-g   ||

||   c   |   h   |   c-h   ||

Here I need to validate the values in column C against the list `{a-c, d-g, c-f}`, if the value is not existing the list, it should block the selection in **A** and **B** columns by showing error message.

I am using **MS Office 2013**

Comment: You can try `Conditional Formatting` because that way you can enter a formula there.  Or you will need to create a hidden sheet and have all the combinations of your valid list and then set up a `Data Validation` with that list selected as a source.

Comment: Can you give me one example since I am less familiar with this formula. How can I restrict the entry when I select a value in `B`, and it does not creating a valid combination with the value in 'A'.

Comment: It is hard to explain in the comment area so I put in the answer below.  But let me know if you see any problem and I will do my best to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is harder than I thought but here is how you can "sort of" make it to work.  Maybe there is another way but this is the idea, see the attached pic,  that I came up with.

[image]

1. **`Columns E, F and G`**: These are the lists that you want to check against with.  The `Good List` is all entered manually.  And `columns F and G` are basically retrieve those good values from the `Good List`.  See `row 6` for formulas.  I also made range names as `GoodList` > `column E`, `GoodListLeft` > `column F` and `GoodListRight` > `columns G`.
2. **`Columns A and B`**: These two columns are also entered manually.  No drop down is implemented here.  But on the `row 9` you can see the validation rule (`Data > Data Validation > Allow field choose Custome, and use the formulas on row 9 into Formula field`).  `Row 9` is the formula for `Data Validation`.

   On **`cell A2`**, enter `=COUNTIF(GoodListLeft,A2)=1`, drag or copy down so you don't need to enter them by hand.  Note that I used `A2` so it will use relative reference when you drag down.

   **`Cell B2`** will be `=COUNTIF(GoodListRight,B2)=1`.
3. **`Cell C2`** I have this formula, `=CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2)` so it will concatenate the strings from `columns A and B`.  But you will need to use `=COUNTIF(GoodList,C2)=1` in the `Data Validation Formula`.

   See this pic for `Data Validation` set up:

   [image]
4. **`Conditional Formatting`**: Under `cell A2`, select `Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...` and enter this formula, `=COUNTIF(GoodList,$C2)=0`.  See pic below.

[image]

And this should apply to `=$A$2:$B$8`

[image]

Hopefully I explained this clearly.  But let me know if you have any problem to implement this.